# Continuous Integration of multiple projects

Tags: continuous-integration

Is there any way to create continuous integration for multiple Java/Scala projects? (Say in [Semaphore](http://semaphoreci.com))

For example project A is using project B. I change project B and push it. If A is always using the latest version of B, it might break due to changes in B. Any CI system which runs both A and B (ordered by their dependance), by changing one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Ervin from Semaphore here.

If you add both of your repositories to the CI and setup B so that on success, it triggers the build of the latest revision of A through the Semaphore [rebuild API call](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/branches-and-builds-api.html#rebuild), I think you'll achieve what you're looking for. This is basically creating a pipeline.

Please stop by on Semaphore support and we'll discuss the details.

Comment: Fantastic! I tried semaphore yesterday and it was very convenient to use. I will give take another look.